# Insert record with PreparedStatementCreator (must run on Oracle & PostgreSQL)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use Spring Jdbc Prepared statement to insert records into a table. This code must run on Postgres and Oracle. I need to read the inserted record key after insertion.

I found the below code on Spring documentation JDBC chapter and it says "this works with Oracle".
[See link here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) (section 12.2.8).

It works on Postgres nicely, inserts the record and I can read inserted record key with keyHolder. However on Oracle it fails with below error message...

> [junit] STDOUT [ERROR] [2011.11.04 01:26:04] ..... - Test ...... failed.
>       [junit] Message: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SOME_USER"."SOME_TABLE"."ID")
>       [junit] ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SOME_USER"."SOME_TABLE"."ID")

Here is the code...

```
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator()
    {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into some_table(xxx_name,xxx_date), new String[] { "id" });
            ps.setString(1, "some name");
            ps.setDate(2, "some date");
            return ps;
        }
    }, keyHolder);
```

Note: I'm using ojdbc6.jar (Oracle jdbc jar), commons dbcp jar

Here is applicationContext dataSource bean

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

I have sequences present both on Postgres and Oracle, for the table `some_table_id_seq`. I have to make this code work for Postgres (runs on devs machines) and Oracle (runs on production). Any help/ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is [no "Postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). It's *PostgreSQL* or *Postgres* for short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown us the table definition (DDL) for Postgres and Oracle, but I guess the ID column is defined as `serial` in Postgres and thus a new ID is automatically retrieved from the sequence that is linked to that column

Oracle does not have such a concept. If you don't want to call `sequence.nextval` manually (which would be possible with Postgres as well) you have to create a trigger that assigns the next sequence value for that column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ins_some_table
  BEFORE INSERT ON some_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.id := some_table_id_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```

Comment: Although I ended up implementing my own solution, I take your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I gave up trying to use the same query for both databases so I have implemented a map with special key names and queries, for Postgres it picks different insert queries and for Oracle it has different queries using xxx_id_seq.nextval.